# Netbeans Find and replace all strings

Tags: netbeans, replace, find, netbeans-7

Is there any way to find all Strings in my source code regardless of their content. In other words I want to find everything that starts and ends with `"` . What I want to do afterwards is replace all found strings with `someMethod(string)`.
**Edit:**

I think I have not expressed myself clear. I want to find all strings no matter what the content between the `"` is and the "encapsulate" them. In your example `syso("test")`  should become `syso(somethod("test"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Find In Project` functionality using the `Basic Wildcards` options.

Then use the `*` wild card and search for `syso(*)` . This will return all occurrences of this method. Then manually you can replace the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

**CTRL+F** - search for `"` and replace manually:

search for :  the thing you want to replace(e.g. ")
replace with: the thing you want to past instead (e.g.someMethod())
-> But look out for errors! think about replacing bevor you try it- because if you replace all " with somemethod, you have a lot of errors! Look at this example:

```
syso("test");
//---replace actoin: someMethod() instead of "
syso(someMethod()testsomeMethod())
```

-> best way is to make this kind of manipulations (in my oppinion): manually!
Perhaps there are some [Refactoring-Tools](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring) in Netbeans which could help you-but i don´t think that there is a "simple and easy" solution.

If you are searching for a solution for the whole project you are working on, go into the Edit menu-y there ou should find a item for "**Replace in Project**";

I hope i understood you right & could help a little!

Comment: I think I have not expressed myself clear. I want to find all strings no matter what the content between " is and the "encapsulate" them. In your example syso("test") should become syso(someMethod("test"));